# How do I fix my rig?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

Im learning the in and outs of blender, and I'm starting to be able to understand most things and fix them on my own, but this one has me stuck.

Im rigging a Halo 5 spartan, and the left forearm right keeps influencing the top of the thigh plate. (Screenshots below)

[image]

And when I move it...

[image]

I have the same problems on the right side too. I have checked the weight painting and its all good, I just cant figure out whats influencing the mesh. This is my fourth time rigging a spartan, and all the rest have gone without a hitch. I don't really want to restart, so please help me out!